# Apply ng-class conditionally

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm displaying an image based on some conditions (i.e. if condition1 is fulfilled then show image1, if condition2 then show image2 and so on).
I'm using `ng-if`. My code looks like this:

```html
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 form-col-pad customization-grid-data text-left"
     ng-if="data.severity==3">
        <img src="App/images/Icons/alarm-high.png">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 form-col-pad customization-grid-data text-left"
     ng-if="data.severity==2">
        <img src="App/images/Icons/alarm-medium.png">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 form-col-pad customization-grid-data text-left"
     ng-if="data.severity==1">
        <img src="App/images/Icons/alarm-low.png">
</div>
```

I'm displaying only 1 image but still I have to write 3 lines of code.
How can I use `ng-class` here so as to minimize the written code?

Answer (score 2):

use ng-src to dynamically change the src of the image, then you only need the code once :)

```
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 form-col-pad customization-grid-data text-left"> 
    <img ng-src="{{img.src}}"> 
</div>
```

Inside Controller:

```
if($scope.data.severity == 2){
    $scope.img.src = 'App/images/Icons/alarm-medium.png';
} else if($scope.data.severity==1){
    $scope.img.src = 'App/images/Icons/alarm-low.png';
}
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out in the comments this will not work if used on more than one on the page.  So here is an alternative.

```
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 form-col-pad customization-grid-data text-left"> 
    <img ng-src="{{ getSeverity(data.severity) }}"> 
</div>
```

-

```
$scope.getSeverity = function(severity){
    if(severity == 2){
         return 'App/images/Icons/alarm-medium.png';
    } else if(severity == 1){
         return 'App/images/Icons/alarm-low.png';
    }
}
```

-

As an off-topic note on your bootstrap code, as a suggestion you can actually lose a lot of your classes on the div. Specifically the col-sm-1 and upwards.  col-xs-1 will apply to sm/md/lg.

```
<div class="col-xs-1 form-col-pad customization-grid-data text-left">
```

Comment: U have put both conditions for data.severity==2

Comment: edited.  The general idea is there at least anyways :)

Comment: This will only work if you have only one of these images on the page. If two or more `data` are included, they will both get the same image (The last one). Also, if `data.severity` changes, the image will not change unless you explicitly set it in your controller again.

Comment: @Arg0n - I feel my answer was perfectly fine specifically for that question. I have however updated my answer to include a different option that can handle multiple images :)

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use ng-switch:

```
<span ng-switch on="data.severity">
   <img ng-switch-when="1" src='App/images/Icons/alarm-low.png'>
   <img ng-switch-when="2" src='App/images/Icons/alarm-medium.png'>
   <img ng-switch-when="3" src='App/images/Icons/alarm-high.png'>
   <img ng-switch-default   src='default image source'>
</span>
```

Comment: Didn't even know this existed!

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 form-col-pad customization-grid-data text-left">
        <img ng-src="{{'App/images/Icons/alarm-' + (data.severity == 1 ? 'low' : (data.severity == 2 ? 'medium' : 'high')) + '.png'}}">
</div>
```

**OR**

HTML

```
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 form-col-pad customization-grid-data text-left">
        <img ng-src="{{getSeveritySrc(data)}}">
</div>
```

JavaScript in Controller

```
$scope.getSeveritySrc = function(data){
    var src = 'App/images/Icons/alarm-';
    switch(data.severity){
        case 1:
            src += 'low';
        break;
        case 2:
            src += 'medium';
        break;
        default:
            src += 'high';
        break;
    }
    src += '.png';
    return src;
}
```

**OR**

Attribute in HTML

```
ng-class="{'low':data.severity == 1,'medium':data.severity == 2,'high':data.severity == 3}"
```

Example CSS

```
.low {
    background: green;
}

.medium {
    background: yellow;
}

.high {
    background: red;
}
```

**OR**

Attribute in HTML

```
ng-class="getSeverityClass(data)"
```

JavaScript in Controller

```
$scope.getSeverityClass = function(data){
    switch(data.severity){
        case 1:
            return 'low';
        break;
        case 2:
            return 'medium';
        break;
        default:
            return 'high';
        break;
    } 
}
```

And a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/njx9w003/3/) to show this working with multiple `data`.

Comment: instead of putting img src=" " in my code,i made class having image url (background:url).In my controller i put a conditon,[that if severity=3(then class="high","severity=2,class="medium",etc.)]and assigned that classname to a variable and by using {{}} in my html applied that class.
This works good for me.Suggest if anything can be optimized.
HTML as:
<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-1 col-lg-1 form-col-pad customization-grid-data text-left {{data.aClassName}}" >
      </div>
if(severity===3){
     aClassName = "high";
     }
     else if(severity===2){
      aClassName = "medium";
     }

Comment: @HarpreetChawla I have updated my answer to use `ng-class` also.

Comment: Your method of ng-class works perfectly but when viewing the DOM of the page (using inspect element ),it exposes the condition(ie-if severity=3,then class=high),which is a bad practise.Thats why i would prefer using my way mentioned above

Comment: Look at this: https://jsfiddle.net/Arg0n/njx9w003/3/ `ng-class` using function (At top). No exposure.

Comment: Btw, in either case, users can look at your JavaScript and see how this is calculated.